# why touchesBegan event in 1stVC triggered by touch from 2ndVC?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue, touches

I met a very strange thing:
in storyboard has to ViewControllers : 1stVC and 2ndVC,
in 1stVC (Initial VC in storyboard) only have 2 functions:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //when touch view in 2ndVC,it will exec here!!!
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    NSLog("xxx")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //switch to 2ndVC
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "2ndVC", sender: nil)
}
```

Because app starts from 1stVC,but at viewDidAppear func it's soon to go to exec performSegue() func to switch to 2ndVC;now app should be in 2ndVC,but when I touch the screen (at 2ndVC's view), it will jump to the 1stVC's touchsBegin func (exec NSLog("xxx")).

How could that happen!? please help me,thanks!!!

Comment: FIX Wrong text : in storyboard has 2 ViewControllers : 1stVC and 2ndVC, in 1stVC (Initial VC in storyboard) only have 2 functions:

Comment: I am use xcode 9.0